# Basic photo gallery CMS

Tags: php, mysql, image-gallery

I know there are lots of gallery scripts out there, but I don't know if any of them will fit my needs. I'm looking for something extremely simple that I can seamlessly incorporate into an existing website to replace the old manually updating every page method. There are 4 categories and an archive, and I'd like to be able to give a title and description to each photo, and search within the 4 categories, or the archive.. The current gallery works with a list of 8-10 thumbnails per page and when you hover over them, a large preview shows up in the empty space at the right. The title and description for each photo is added in photoshop to each image, which is a big reason to update this (this was done by the original web designer, not me).

The server runs linux with PHP and MySQL.
Does anyone know of something that fits my needs, or is simple enough for me to modify to meet my requirements?

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the replies, but these aren't really what I'm looking for; sorry for not making it clearer. I want a CMS type system where I can easily add the photos through an admin panel and then have the front-end a bit more up to me.

Answer (score 0):

My personal fave, not so known but very stylish and easy to use:

http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/

One of the most widespread and very easy to setup is Lightbox 2:

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

There are a ton of others, you can google for "lightbox script"
and find something that maybe fits your taste more.

But for these 2 I can say from personal experience that are
stable, work nicely and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I set up something for my wife to link work samples during a job search. I used smoothgallery ( http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/ ) which is very lightweight. It is just the gallery UI essentially, and basically rewrites the DOM for a specially tagged unordered list if I remember correctly. So the gallery organization is up to you, but its as easy as a little php + mysql to output the list.